# matplotlib numeric values are plotted out of order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data file that consist of multiple y (+ve and -ve values of y) values corresponding to a single x value, if I am trying to plot it using the matplotlib I am getting a zig-zag line, I even tried with the `np.sort` function, but it hasn't helped. I am attaching 2 figures, the 1 one what I need and 2 one what I am getting using the matplotlib. Any comment/suggestion will be a great help.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {0: [0.9991008043, 0.7186818868, 0.5990678817, 0.000260249999, -0.0002838699947, 0.9982619435, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.5990678817, 0.9987124801, 0.9983241558, 0.9979358315, 0.9975475073],
        1: [0.141599882, -0.0239639965, -0.8235306015, -0.5624349256, 0.9576566094, 0.1070839175, -0.7615373918, -0.7436025052, -0.7207683284, -0.7181828611, -0.7169656166, -0.7189734963, -0.7248864019, -0.7334572909, -0.7431326927, -0.7535460886, -0.7653977208, -0.7772543193, -0.7850276183, -0.7882964598, -0.788996217, -0.7894645357, -0.7800111345, -0.7680467609, -0.7651210906, -0.7626205455, 0.1662477571, 0.1776703065, 0.178896989, 0.1792297328]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

          0         1
0  0.999101  0.141600
1  0.718682 -0.023964
2  0.599068 -0.823531

plt.plot( df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1], marker="o", linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- In this case, the data is correctly cast as numeric (e.g. `float`), but it's usually a good idea to verify the column `dtypes` with `df.info()`
- It's required to sort the x-axis values with `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()`

  - I typically also reset the index, but it's not strictly necessary.
- Using `pandas v1.2.4` and `matplotlib v3.4.2`

```py
# sort the values for the x-axis, which is column 0
df = df.sort_values(0).reset_index(drop=True)

# plot the sorted data
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1], marker="o", linewidth=2)
```

[image]

- It's also possible to plot the data with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

```py
df.plot(x=0, y=1, marker='o', legend=False)
```